ValueError: The model did not return a loss from the inputs: During Further Pretraining ARBERT Model
I am applying further pretraining for the ARBERT model for both the Masked Language Modeling (MLM) and Next Sentence Prediction (NSP) tasks. However, I am receiving the below error. I know this error arises if I don't name my dataset columns as "text" and "labels". I am already naming my dataset column as "text". I don't have a "labels" one since it is an unsupervised task. Also, as far as I know, the "labels" here should be the Tokens of MLM and NSP ([MASK], [CLS], [NSP]) which should be handled automatically by the DataCollator function. So, can anyone advice me on this?
ValueError: The model did not return a loss from the inputs, only the following keys: prediction_logits,seq_relationship_logits. For reference, the inputs it received are input_ids,attention_mask,labels.
Note: I receive this error upon initializing the "Trainer":
trainer_mlm = Trainer(model=ARBERT_model, args=training_args, data_collator=data_collator_mlm, train_dataset=train_dataset_for_mlm) 
